# Executing a stored procedure on a linked server to use objects on the local machine

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have a stored procedure deployed on a linked server (server A). I'm trying to do two things:

1. execute the stored procedure from a job on my local machine (server B)
2. have the stored procedure on server A use a database that lives on server B

So far, I can do step one using a four-part reference.

I'm having trouble doing step two. The stored procedure is looking for its own local objects - objects on server A. I'd like the stored procedure to use objects on the calling server (server B).

I'd like to be able to set up multiple servers, each of which will have identically named objects, to call the remote stored procedure but which uses the local objects when processing.

Any thoughts on this? Do I have to localize the database reference in the stored procedure? Can I pass through a parameter? Does server A need a linked server connection back to B, C, and D?

Comment: You would need to also create a linked server on the other server pointing to the first.  If you are doing cross database joins, I would be very careful.  I avoid them like the plague.  If it's a little data, I would pull it into a temp table and join with that, if that's what you need.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to avoid the two-way linked server arrangement. I will have multiple servers set up with the same database objects but the data itself will differ. I want to use the remote server to store the logic for processing the data on the other servers - a sort of hub and spoke arrangement so I can manage the code in one spot.